# How do I create a loop that repeats drawing a random rank and suit for two playing cards until one rank is higher and there is a clear winner?

Tags: java, loops

```
public class War2
{
    public void warCall()
    {
        System.out.println("WAR is CALLED!");
        
        for(int counter = 1; counter <= 11; ++counter)
        {
            Dealer gameDealer = new Dealer();
            Card computerCard = new Card();
            Card playerCard = new Card();
            String computerCardSuit = computerCard.getSuit((int)(Math.random() * 100) % 4 + 1);
            int computerCardRank = computerCard.getRank();
            String playerCardSuit = playerCard.getSuit((int)(Math.random() * 100) % 4 + 1);
            int playerCardRank = playerCard.getRank();
            boolean playerWins = (playerCardRank > computerCardRank);
            boolean computerWins = (computerCardRank > playerCardRank);
            boolean tie = (computerCardRank == playerCardRank);
            String result = ""; 
            
            if(counter < 11)
                result = "Discard";
            
            if(counter == 11 && (computerWins))
                result = "Computer wins";
            else
                if(counter == 11 && (playerWins))
                    result = "Player wins";
                else
                    if(counter == 11 && (tie))
                        result = "Tie"; 
            
            System.out.println(computerCardRank + " of " + computerCardSuit + "\t\t" + 
                playerCardRank + " of " + playerCardSuit + "\t\t" + result);
            
            
        }
        
    }
}
```

This class(War2) and its method( warCall() ) are called from another class when there is a tie in a game of War. This is the way the output looks:

This is the way the game starts. This part of the program works fine.A Dealer class executes the code below. When the result is a tie (card ranks are equal, in this case 4), the Dealer class invokes the warCall() method from the War2 class. The car suit is assigned randomly using a switch statement from a randomly drawn number from 1 to 4. The getSuit() method takes an integer argument but returns a String, depending on the random number drawn. This information doesn't relate exactly to my question, but I want to give an idea of how the program works.

```
--------------------------------------------------------
Computer Player         Human Player            Result
4 of Clubs              4 of Hearts             Tie
-------------------------------------------------------
```

This is the output from the War2 class:

```
WAR is CALLED!
2 of Hearts             12 of Clubs             Discard
10 of Spades            3 of Spades             Discard
8 of Spades             1 of Clubs              Discard
4 of Spades             13 of Hearts            Discard
1 of Diamonds           6 of Spades             Discard
3 of Diamonds           3 of Diamonds           Discard
11 of Diamonds          10 of Hearts            Discard
8 of Hearts             9 of Clubs              Discard
13 of Hearts            9 of Diamonds           Discard
1 of Diamonds           1 of Clubs              Discard
3 of Spades             5 of Spades             Player wins
```

What I need is for the above process to repeat in the event of a tie (when counter is 11 and rank of both cards is the same), within the War2 class. I have attached my code for War2 so that you can see what I have done so far. How can I make all of this output repeat if there is a tie until there is a clear winner?

I have tried using do and do while loops without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply loop if the result is "Tie"

```
String result = "";
while(result.equals("") || result.equals("Tie")){
   // do the for loop
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been trying the most complicated solutions for days without success. It was so simple all along! Your answer showed me exactly what I needed to do without a wordy, complicated response.  Thank you again!